# Como mudar o Background2 quando a bola colidir com a bordas

Tags: if, else, background, background-image

Eu queria saber como faz o Background mudar de imagem na classe,Quando a bolinha for igual a 1 ,Quero que mudar o Background para Background para background2,Qual código eu usaria para mudar o Background2.

```
{
  
    this.y = this.y + this.velocidadeY;
    if (this.y > 599) {
    this.y = -600
    }
    
    if(bolabateu = 1){
        console.log(bolabateu);
    }
    if(bolabateu = 0){
        this.x = 0;
    }
    
}
```

}
E quando eu dou o Play,no Jogo,A variável bolabateu já começa com 1,Eu queria que começasse com 0,E só quando a Bola bastasse na borda da Esquerda ficasse o valor da variável bolabateu = 1,E quando a bolabateu fosse igual a 1 mudasse o Background2 como eu expliquei acima,Como eu faço,Seguir o código abaixo que puder por favor me ajude?

```
TestandoLimite()
{
    if(this.x <= 0)
    {
        this.velocidadeX = -this.velocidadeX;
        this.bolabateu = 1;
    }
    
    if(this.y >= 540)
    {
        this.velocidadeY = -this.velocidadeY;
        this.bolabateu = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Eu queria que por exemplo,Quando a bola batesse na borda da esquerda fosse escolhida a Imagem1,Mas eu não sei como eu faço o código no If para mudar o Background2 Eu já tentei por

Exemplo:

'''
If(if(this.x <= 0)
{
Eu queria que quando a Bola colidir se com a borda esquerda,Imagem2 fosse escolhida,Mas eu não sei qual código para mudar o Background para Background2

```
     }
```

'''

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Você está perguntando como se soubéssemos de informações que estão apenas na sua mente. Contextualize-nos e apresente um [mcve] para que possamos replicar em nossos computadores especificamente o cenário problemático para ai podermos intercambiar informações

Answer (score -1):

TestandoLimite()
{
if(this.x <= 0)
{
this.velocidadeX = -this.velocidadeX;
this.bolabateu = 1;
}

```
if(this.y >= 540)
{
    this.velocidadeY = -this.velocidadeY;
    this.bolabateu = 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).